# Is there a way to retrieve the shared key from the Azure Blob Storage Account using API calls

Tags: azure, rest, storage

I was able to create new Storage account by making rest API call and using info (client id, secret, etc) of the principal which I created for this purpose.
After creation of the new azure storage account I would like to continue (create containers, upload blobs etc) by using this account but for that I need the access key which I am not able (for now) to get from the API.

Is there a way to do this or I need to go to Azure portal after creation of each storage account and to pick the access key from there?

Mirko

Answer (score 0):

Everything  you can do in the Azure portal can be done with a REST API.

And almost everything is also available in Powershell and the Azure CLI.

The service teams ship the REST API changes when they make changes to the servcie.  Those changes sometimes take some time to appear in the PowerShell, CLI and the language APIs.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-powershell

And I believe the REST API is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/listkeys

Comment: Hello David, thank you for your answer. But could you tell me what is the actual API call that I have to make? In the doc you shared it does not say anything about that.

Comment: *Most* everything is available in Powershell and the Azure CLI. Implementation lags changes to the REST API by some period of time. Example? Status code ranges for App Service Auto Heal. As of this date, you can set it with the API, but Powershell Az and Az CLI don't support it yet. Exporting the Resource Group doesn't even do it. I say this not to be argumentative, rather to say that I've found myself frustrated when features don't make it into the script platforms.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!